# Como criar uma URL amigável com número de parâmetros indefinido

Tags: regex, htaccess

Olá, alguém saberia como fazer essa expressão regular no .htaccess?

Preciso deixar o padrão da URL amigável neste formato:

```
http://dominio.com.br/usuario/joao.json
http://dominio.com.br/usuario/adriano.json
http://dominio.com.br/usuario/henrique.json
```

Para retornar o seguinte arquivo num esquema de diretórios configurado dessa forma:

```
/usuario/j/o/a/o/data.json
/usuario/a/d/r/i/a/n/o/data.json
/usuario/h/e/n/r/i/q/u/e/data.json
```

Sabendo que o usuário pode variar de tamanho, podendo ter mais de 10 caracteres, como criar uma expressão regular com o número de parâmetros indefinido?

Comment: Esse é o problema real, ou você tentou fazer um "exemplo"?  Pode até ser que alguém consiga ajudar com a resposta, mas me parece que a arquitetura vai te dar uma série de outros problemas. Se REALMENTE precisa disso (apesar de eu estar meio cético quanto a isso), melhor seria usar uma linguagem do lado do servidor, que dê mais liberdade, em vez de querer resolver com .htaccess e RegEx.

Comment: É o problema real. Essa acabou sendo a melhor forma de organizar os usuários tendo em vista o limite físico de 32 mil diretórios/arquivos (sistema de arquivos EXT3) dentro de um mesmo diretório (no momento são mais de 500 mil usuários). Estou resolvendo isso no momento com o PHP, mas com essa expressão eu poderia desviar diretamente para o arquivo de cache .json em vez de processar com PHP.

Comment: creio que com PHP + X-Sendfile seria mais fácil, eliminaria boa parte do problema de ocupar o PHP para envio dos dados. Mesmo assim, para fazer com diretorios, poderia dividir um pouco menos, em vez de letra a letra. Por exemplo, pegando somente 2 ou 3 iniciais. Se bem que neste caso, com o volume mencionado, o ideal seria servir em aplicação própria, em vez de servidor web comum. Simplificaria tudo.

Comment: Um login nosso é composto por por até 30 caracteres possibilitando 26 letras, 10 dígitos e underline, ou seja 37 possibilidades por caractere. Levando em consideração o agrupamento por 2 caracteres para diminuir o número de termos seria uma variação de 37*37 = 1.369 possibilidades em um diretório (um caractere a mais já deixaria em 50.653 possibilidades extrapolando o limite físico de 32 mil). Mesmo agrupando em apenas 2 caracteres, seria necessário estabelecer 15 variáveis na expressão, e até onde sei só podemos usar 9.

Comment: Especifique qual a linguagem (php, asp, jsp, etc) pois não é algo que se resolve pelo regex do mod_rewrite.

Comment: Dá pra ter mais que 9, só muda um pouco a sintaxe. De qualquer forma, como comentei, seriam 4 padrões, um para cada letra, e depois o nome completo (ou o que sobrar dele): `/usuario/a/d/a/adalberto.json` ou mesmo `/usuario/a/d/a/adalberto/data.json`, quem sabe `/usuario/a/d/a/lberto/data.json`. Isso é simples com RegEx, pois passa a ser fixo. Notando que são só exemplos, poderia ser `/ma/xi/miliano/data.json` se quisesse grupos de 2 letras.

Comment: Não poderia usar o id do usuário? Usando o login funciona sem problemas mas estará "engessando" o sistema pois ficará bem complicado se precisar um dia oferecer ao usuário trocar o nome do login.

Comment: Daniel, a ideia é só desviar do PHP direto pro arquivo pronto .json com .htaccess.

Comment: Bacco, como se usa mais de 9 variáveis na expressão? Entendi o que você quis dizer agora, usando só os primeiros 3 caracteres deixaria o terceiro sobrecarregado com o número de possibilidades do resto dos caracteres.

Comment: Daniel, seria ótimo se eu pudesse usar o ID, ou melhor um ID convertido em hexadecimal para ser menor, o problema é que existem muitos JS que solicitam informações de usuários pelo login já que seria inviável as pessoas lembrarem de seus ID's, então eu teria que processar um script extra (com consulta ao banco, o que seria um pesadelo) só para relacionar logins e ID's. A ideia é evitar processamento, por isso o desvio pelo .htaccess, porque passando pelo PHP eu posso fazer qualquer coisa.

Comment: @RogerWolff para contornar os 9 parâmetros, você pode fazer uma cascata com mais de um rewrite. Sei que estou insistindo demais na idéia, mas não consigo imaginar um caso real que precise disso. Mesmo coisas com volume muito superior ao seu caso não fazem isso. Com apenas 3 letras, você já teria 15548 diretórios diferentes. Claro que na prática dá menos, por não ser linear, mas deveria ser mais que suficiente. Respeito seu direito de fazer suas coisas como quiser, mas tenho a forte impressão que está longe de ser uma solução boa. Solução com .htaccess não é tão melhor que PHP a esse ponto.

Comment: @Bacco, sobre a estrutura de diretórios não tenho problemas, inclusive tenho uma classe em PHP que administra essa estrutura como se não houvesse diferença. Voltando a questão do tópico, sobre o número indefinido de parâmetros, como seria essa cascata para contornar o limite dos 9 parâmetros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi comentado que deve haver melhor maneira para organizar pastas.

Esta seria a solução. É assumido que os nomes de usuário são letras `[a-z]`.

**.htaccess**

```python
RewriteEngine on

# URL:                  Reescrita:
# usuario/ab/c/d.json   usuario/a/b/c/d.json
# usuario/abc/d.json    usuario/ab/c/d.json
# usuario/abcd.json     usuario/abc/d.json
RewriteRule ^(usuario/[a-z]+)([a-z])((?:/[a-z])*\.json)$ $1/$2$3  [N]

# URL:                  Reescrita:
# usuario/a.json        usuario/a/data.json
# usuario/a/b.json      usuario/a/b/data.json
# usuario/a/b/c.json    usuario/a/b/c/data.json
# usuario/a/b/c/d.json  usuario/a/b/c/d/data.json
RewriteRule ^(usuario(?:/[a-z])+)\.json$ $1/data.json             [L]
```

**Exemplo:**

```
http://dominio.com.br/usuario/umnomedeusuariomuitolongo.json
```

**Reescrita:**

```
http://dominio.com.br/usuario/u/m/n/o/m/e/d/e/u/s/u/a/r/i/o/m/u/i/t/o/l/o/n/g/o/data.json
```

**Descrição:**

- O regex corresponde à última letra consecutiva no nome do usuário, adicionando o caractere `/`.
- O [sinalizador](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) [`[N]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) faz com que a regra seja executada novamente se corresponder.
- A regra é executada novamente para cada caractere, ea url é reescrita novamente após o último caractere é substituído, até que não haja mais caracteres para reescrever.
- Se o sinalizador `[N]` não for compatível com sua versão de Apache, pode alterá-lo para `[L]`, mas você deve alterar [MaxRedirects](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteOptions) para permitir muitas iterações.

Comment: Eu havia percebido minutos depois que estava fazendo loop até casar com a primeira regra. Isso realmente parece dar certo mas em um certo momento acontece 500 Internal Server Error com nomes muito grandes. Ainda não entendo o porquê. Tente com "umnomedeusuariomuitolongo" e me diga se acontece com você também?

Comment: @RogerWolff Isso depende do [MaxRedirects](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteOptions)... Eu editei a resposta, usando [`[N]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n), para considerar esse caso. Pode testar http://mariano.freevar.com/157848/usuario/umnomedeusuariomuitolongo.json

Comment: Realmente, agora funcionou. Fiz algumas alterações como aumentar a lista de possíveis caracteres que meus usuários utilizam no login [a-z0-9_] e funcionou perfeitamente. Isso me ajudou muito. Obrigado.